# How can I expand multiple lists in the same task

Tags: yaml, ansible

I have a situation where I have two different variables, which I want to reference in a single command:

For example, I am expecting the following as output :

```
list 1
  item a
  item b
list 2
  another item from different var 10

-name : Run a module which executes a command on a host eg. via ssh
command:
  host: {{ device_ip }}
  cmd_str: 
   - 'list 1 '
    - '  {{ item item[0].name }}'
   - 'list 2 '
    - '  {{ another item from different var item[1].id }}'
  with_items:
   - {{ var1 }}
   - {{ var2 }}

var1:
   - { name:a, address:test }
   - { name:b, address:test2 }

var2:
   - { name:x, id:10 }
```

What do I write instead of ***"with_items"*** to get this done?

The issue is how do I expand two different variables, in the same place without having to iterate the entire command (this is do-able if I move with_items to the same indentation level as the module invocation)

Comment: What do you mean by single command? A single task? It looks like in your `command` you have two different tasks. If you have two tasks then what is the relation between the lists? Do they have same number of items? Or you just want to traverse two lists one by one. A more concrete example of tasks will be better to understand.

Comment: This is a single task, with the command being built by combining the items below it. For example, a set of instructions to send to a device.

Answer (score 3):

I cannot understand what you actually want to do, but the following playbook demonstrates:

- Passing multiple vars in a single item using dict
- Iterating over each var using Jinja2 template

playbook.yml:

```
---
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: no
  vars:
    var1:
      - { name: a, address: test }
      - { name: b, address: test2 }
    var2:
      - { name: x, id: 10 }
  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: |
          list 1
          {% for x in item.1 %}
            item {{x.name}}
          {% endfor %}
          list 2
          {% for x in item.2 %}
            another item from different var {{x.id}}
          {% endfor %}
      with_items:
        - { 1: "{{var1}}", 2: "{{var2}}" }
    - shell: |
        >/tmp/output.txt # truncate file
        {% for x in item.1 %}
        echo item {{x.name}} >>/tmp/output.txt
        {% endfor %}
        {% for x in item.2 %}
        echo another item from different var {{x.id}} >>/tmp/output.txt
        {% endfor %}
      with_items:
        - { 1: "{{var1}}", 2: "{{var2}}" }
```

Sample session:

```
$ ansible-playbook -i localhost, playbook.yml 

PLAY [all] ******************************************************************** 

TASK: [debug ] **************************************************************** 
ok: [localhost] => (item={1: [{'name': 'a', 'address': 'test'}, {'name': 'b', 'address': 'test2'}], 2: [{'name': 'x', 'id': 10}]}) => {
    "item": {
        "1": [
            {
                "address": "test", 
                "name": "a"
            }, 
            {
                "address": "test2", 
                "name": "b"
            }
        ], 
        "2": [
            {
                "id": 10, 
                "name": "x"
            }
        ]
    }, 
    "msg": "list 1\n  item a\n  item b\nlist 2\n  another item from different var 10\n"
}

TASK: [shell >/tmp/output.txt # truncate file
{% for x in item.1 %}
echo item {{x.name}} >>/tmp/output.txt
{% endfor %}
{% for x in item.2 %}
echo another item from different var {{x.id}} >>/tmp/output.txt
{% endfor %}
] *** 
changed: [localhost] => (item={1: [{'name': 'a', 'address': 'test'}, {'name': 'b', 'address': 'test2'}], 2: [{'name': 'x', 'id': 10}]})

PLAY RECAP ******************************************************************** 
localhost                  : ok=2    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0
```

Output shown in `msg` from `debug` module:

```
list 1
  item a
  item b
list 2
  another item from different var 10
```

Output in `/tmp/output.txt` from `shell` module:

```
item a
item b
another item from different var 10
```

Comment: Thank  you, this is very close to what I expect.Couple of queries : 1. How can I have list 1, item a, item b etc each be an element of a list (i.e, I need to pass these individually to a command in place of msg. 2. What does the "|" after msg: do ? Any documentation around this ?

Comment: Updated my answer.  I suggest to write a script with your commands populated by jinja2 template and execute it by `shell` module.  `|` is common YAML syntax to express [block literals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YAML#Block_literals): it's very useful for embedding a multi-line text or script in Ansible playbooks.  And I always reommend to pass module arguments in the form of a dict like this playbook where `|` is available, i.e. use `debug: { msg: text }` rather than `debug: msg=text`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the Ansible docs page on loops: http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_loops.html

I think you are looking for either nested loops, subelements, or looping over parallel sets.

Comment: Nested loops and parallel sets are not applicable here. Nested loops provide m*n values, and parallel sets require both lists to be same length. Not sure about subelements, could not get it working yet.